# SAS Data step free format issue

Tags: regex, sas, datastep

I would like to include a line feed before the keyword 'data-base-url' only when it doesnt have one.

### Input File

```
    </html>
    <et1>
    <a data-linked-resource-type="userinfo" data-base-url="https://url.com/c">USERNAME 1</a>
    <td class="conTd">
    INFO 1
    </td>
    </et1>

    <et2>
    <a data-linked-resource-type="userinfo" 

    data-base-url="https://url.com/c1">USERNAME 2</a>
    <td class="conTd">
    INFO 2
    </td>
    </et2>

    <et3>
    <a data-linked-resource-type="userinfo" 
    data-base-url=
    "https://url.com/c2">USERNAME 3</a>
    <td class="conTd">
    INFO 3
    </td>
    </et3>
    </html>
```

---

```
    /* data program */
    data inp;
    infile "c:/tmp/output.txt";
    input @'data-base-url=' user_info $30000. 
    @'<td class="conTd">' details $30000.;
    run;
    /* data program ends */
```

et3 tag is the required pattern. If you run the above program for the input file, you will get only the et3 tag gets converted properly to the user_info and details columns but I would like to include the line feed in the first two tags to get the desired output. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
AKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution which is based on your output dataset `inp` rather than your question per se as with this solution there is no need to modify your input file.

Basically you read every line of your input file as a single SAS row and manipulate data from there. Modify record length at your convinience.

```
  data inp;
    infile "/sascr/user/me/output.txt" truncover lrecl=200;
    input string $200. ;
    lstr = lag(string);
    if lstr='<td class="conTd">' then details = string;
    if string='<td class="conTd">' then _info = lstr;
    user_info = scan(lag(_info),-1,'=');
    if length(strip(details))>1 then output;
    keep details user_info;
 run;
```

Hope this help.